# RESTful Resource Naming for POST

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, soa, restful-architecture

Giving this naming convention:

http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

for the POST (insert) the url of the resource should follow this path/logic:

```
 http://www.example.com/products/X123
 {
       "color":"something"
 }
```

Is the following path conceptually wrong? and why is it correct/wrong?

```
 http://www.example.com/products
 {
       "id":"X123"
       "color":"something"
 }
```

*the ID is generated externally*

Also for the PUT is it ok to apply the same logic? (the id naturally must not be changed but used only as ref)

Thank you

Comment: can you be more specific: is it correct that the client gets to decide the ID of the created resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For POST (which is usually used to create a new item in collection) use the following:

```
http://www.example.com/products
{
   "color":"something"
}
```

if you have a requirement where client generated the id, the it is

```
http://www.example.com/products
{
   "id": "abc123"
   "color":"something"
}
```

EDIT:

For PUT it should be:

```
http://www.example.com/products/abc123
{
   "color":"something else"
}
```

Comment: What about the PUT?
do you think it's correct to add the _id_ in the url or in the body of the request?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your scenario suits best for PUT method, I would always prefer to include id in url if I only know it - that would be the clearest solution for others.

Second part about including id in body, there is nice answer about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28108844/3301697
The only thing I would change in this answer is to include id to every PUT request, if you know it, why hide it.